# How to build the correct LINQ query (generate OR instead of AND)

Tags: sql, linq

I need some help in building the correct query. I have an Employees table. I need to get a list of all employees, that EENO (Employee ID) contains a string from a supplied array of partial Employee IDs.

When I use this code

```
// IEnumerable<string> employeeIds is a collection of partial Employee IDs
IQueryable<Employee> query = Employees;
foreach (string id in employeeIds)
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.EENO.Contains(id));
}
return query;
```

I will get something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employees 
WHERE EENO LIKE '%1111111%' 
  AND EENO LIKE '%2222222%' 
  AND EENO LIKE '%3333333%' 
  AND EENO LIKE '%4444444%'
```

Which doesn't make sense. 
**I need "OR" instead of "AND" in resulting SQL.**

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

This code I wrote using PredicateBuilder **works perfectly** when I need to include these employees.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Employee>();
foreach (string id in employeeIds)
{
    var temp = id;
    predicate = predicate.Or(e => e.EENO.Contains(temp));
}
var query = Employees.Where(predicate);
```

Now, I need to write an opposite code, to exclude these employees, 
here it is **but it is not working**: the generated SQL is totally weird.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Employee>();
foreach (string id in employeeIds)
{
    var temp = id;
    predicate = predicate.And(e => !e.EENO.Contains(temp)); // changed to "And" and "!"
}
var query = Employees.Where(predicate);
return query;
```

It's supposed to generate SQL  Where clause like this one:

```
WHERE EENO NOT LIKE '%11111%'
       AND NOT LIKE '%22222%'
       AND NOT LIKE '%33333%'
```

**But it's not happening**

The SQL generated is this: http://i.imgur.com/9MDP7.png

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Actually not, here is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/9MDP7.png

Comment: For the `NOT LIKE` case that you're trying to implement, be sure you start with the TRUE case. It will ALWAYS return false no matter what, because `FALSE && ...` will always resolve to false. You need to start with `PredicateBuilder.True<Employee>()` first.

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver I totally misread the bit where you said _this is what it's supposed to do_ orz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx.  This has a great way of building Or queries, and is written by the guy that wrote LinqPad.  The above link also has examples of usage.

Comment: I second that recommendation. Otherwise, you'd have to keep your original query in-tact and keep a running query. I'll post what I'm talking about in a separate answer.

Comment: Thank you !!! I have used the PredicateBuilder and it worked.
However I was able to build a query I need to include employees, when I try to build a query to exclude employees, the SQL generated makes no sense, Please see the UPDATE to the post with a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `foreach`, just build the IQueryable once:

```
query = query.Where(e => employeeIds.Contains(e.EENO));
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I need.
It's actually the opposite: e.EENO should contain employeeId.
Because EENO is a FULL id, but employeeId is a partialID.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `Any()`:

```
var query = Employees.Where(emp => employeeIds.Any(id => id.Contains(emp.EENO)));
```

Comment: Any creates the same problem as Union, it gets translated into nested UNION statements in SQL, therefore I get stuck when I reach nesting levele allowed in SQL. And it's around 48. I may have a list of 200 partial IDs. There is no way SQL can handle 200 nested UNIONS. That's what get's built when using this expression.

I believe the only way to do this is use PredicateBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a predicate builder, then the only other option is to UNION each of the collections together on an intermediate query:

```
// IEnumerable<string> employeeIds is a collection of partial Employee IDs
IQueryable<Employee> query = Enumerable.Empty<Employee>().AsQueryable();
foreach (string id in employeeIds)
{
    string tempID = id;
    query = query.Union(Employees.Where(e => e.EENO.Contains(tempID));
}
return query;
```

Also keep in mind that closure rules are going to break your predicate and only end up filtering on your last criteria. That's why I have the `tempID` variable inside the `foreach` loop.

EDIT: So here's the compendium of all the issues you've run across:

**Generate ORs instead of ANDS**

Done, using PredicateBuilder.

**Only last predicate is being applied**

Addressed by assigning a temp variable in your inner loop (due to closure rules)

**Exclusion predicates not working**

You need to start with the correct base case. When you use `OR`s, you need to make sure you start with the `false` case first, that way you only include records where AT LEAST ONE predicate matches (otherwise doesn't return anything). The reason for this is that the base case should just get ignored for purposes of evaluation. In other words `false || predicate1 || predicate2 || ...` really is just `predicate1 || predicate2 || ...` because you're looking for at least one true in your list of predicates (and you just need a base to build on). The opposite applies to the `AND` case. You start with `true` so that it gets "ignored" for purposes of evaluation, but you still need a base case. In other words: `true && predicate1 && ...` is the same as `predicate1 && ...`. Hope that addresses your last issue.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! 
That closure rule indeed broke my predicate, only the last criteria worked. Added temp variable like u suggested and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this COMPLETELY answered his question, just fixed one of the many issues he had. The real answer is the Predicate Builder suggestion, coupled with the closure semantics issue. I'll edit my response so that it addresses all sides.